# Enterprise Architect - Execute SQL Issue

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I'm getting the error "DAO.Database[3464] Data type mismatch in criteria expression." when attempting to update the t_connector table in Enterprise Architect by using the undocumented `Execute` command. Is what I'm trying to do not supported by EA's Execute SQL capabilities?

**What I'm Doing**

Note: This is within a loop so `index` is just an int. `connector` is an EA.Connector.

```
String addTrigger = "UPDATE t_connector SET PDATA1 = " + "'SAMPLE" + index + "'" 
                    + " WHERE Connector_ID = " + "'" + connector.ConnectorID + "';";

repository.Execute(addTrigger);
```

**My Guess**

I don't know SQL very well... did I mess up the statement somehow?

**Further Information**

A previous question I asked that lead me to what I'm doing now:
[Add Trigger to Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849221/ea-add-trigger-to-transition)

Comment: My best guess is that one of your columns has a type that you are not actually giving. For example, if a column contains integers and you try to insert a string you may get an error like this. I don't know which column is causing the error, or which type is mismatched though, but I would start there.

Comment: You were totally right. Rookie mistake. ConnectorID required an int, not a string.

Comment: A much easier mistake to make when you're using prepared statements like this. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @McAdam331 for your comment. Indeed, ConnectorID requires an int, not a string. Remove ' ' around connector.ConnectorID

```
String addTrigger = "UPDATE t_connector SET PDATA1 = " + "'SAMPLE" + index + "'" 
                    + " WHERE Connector_ID = " + connector.ConnectorID + ";";

repository.Execute(addTrigger);
```